# Virtual Service retry with the mesh gateway

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

If the virtual service is used with the `mesh` gateway then `retryRemoteLocalities` and `attempts` are not working. Is it by design or I am missing something?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  hosts:
    - myapp.default.svc.cluster.local

  gateways:
    - mesh

  http:
    - name: myapp
      route:
        - destination:
            host: myapp
            port:
              number: 8000

      retries:
        attempts: 5
        retryOn: 500,502,retriable-status-codes,connect-failure,reset,gateway-error,refused-stream
        retryRemoteLocalities: true
```

Istio 1.14.1
Kubernetes: 1.24.3

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: I didn't manage to solve it. We had to implement retry feature in our application.

Comment: Try this similar [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66345392/istio-sidecar-to-retry-on-specified-status-codes-503) may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: This issue is related to the `mesh` gateway setting and not to status code.

Comment: In the yaml configuration, Delete “retryRemoteLocalities: true”, and add perTryTimeout :2s. For details refer to HTTPRetry.

Comment: Remote localities must be tried. Otherwise, it is useless for me. I am unable to find the reason it should not work as expected.